# Как исправить ошибку компилятора CS1503?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Скрин проги]

Собственно у DXMenuItem есть конструктор с параметрами string, void.Так вот ему не нравится как я вызываю функцию Count с параметрами.Не может конвертировать тип.Как мне правильно вызвать функцию с параметрами?Подозреваю что надо использовать лямбда-функцию,но не уверен.

Comment: вы не показываете ни сигнатуры методов, ни сигнатуры конструкторов, ни вообще что и зачем вы делаете - какого ответа вы ждете? Попробуте сами ответить на вопрос `я вызываю foo(bar()) но не работает, как исправить?`

Comment: Это было не правильно с моей стороны.Добавил описание метода.В принципе по коду все понятно ,что я хочу сделать.

Comment: 1) прикрепляйте пожалуйста код текстом, а не картинками. 2) Приведите [минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) так как после вашего апдейта все ещё не понятно, где проблема. Что за тип этот DXMenuItem и какая у него сигнатура?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У конструктора [`DxMenuItem`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXMenuItem..ctor.overloads), всего две перегрузки с двумя параметрами:

```
DXMenuItem(string caption, DXMenuItemPriority priority)
DXMenuItem(string caption, EventHandler click)
```

Вероятнее всего имелась ввиду вторая перегрузка принимающая обработчик click.

В этом случае действительно можно передать lambda

```
new DxMenuItem(str, (s,e)=> Count(...))
```

Comment: Да все верно.Видимо вы знакомы с DevExpress.Спасибо большое!Вот я не понимал как это технически реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в ожидаемых типах параметров конструктора `DXMenuItem`. Вряд ли тип второго параметра `void` (.

> Собственно у делегата DXMenuItem есть конструктор с параметрами
>   string, void.

Маловероятно также, что тип `DXMenuItem` является делегатом. Похоже, в процитированной фразе Вы пытаетесь описать сигнатуру метода: параметр - `string`, возвращаемое значение - `void`.

Comment: хорошо вам, вам гномики подсказывают, а я вот совсем не вник что у автора за проблема, но определенно с типами параметров

Comment: Я сразу понял ,что он не void.Дело в том ,что я пока не понимаю как вызвать Count с возвращаемым типом void одновременно передав параметры.